# rhel + how to increase sdb1 after increasing sdb disk

Tags: rhel, fdisk, parted, xfs

on our `rhel 7.2 VM` server we increased the `sdb` disk ( not LVM ) from 200 to 220G , as the following  ( sdb is with  xfs fs )

```
sdb                8:16   0  200G  0 disk
└─sdb1             8:17   0  200G  0 part /data
```

after re-scan

```
echo 1 > /sys/block/sdb/device/rescan


sdb                8:16   0  220G  0 disk
└─sdb1             8:17   0  200G  0 part /data
```

now we try to update sdb1 , so sdb1 will be with +20g

```
xfs_growfs  /dev/sdb1
meta-data=/dev/sdb1              isize=256    agcount=4, agsize=8519616 blks
         =                       sectsz=512   attr=2, projid32bit=1
         =                       crc=0        finobt=0
data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=34078464, imaxpct=25
         =                       sunit=0      swidth=0 blks
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0 ftype=0
log      =internal               bsize=4096   blocks=16639, version=2
         =                       sectsz=512   sunit=0 blks, lazy-count=1
realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0
```

but sdb1 still not change by +20g

```
df /data
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1      136247300 133453728   2793572  98% /data
```

and

```
sdb                8:16   0  220G  0 disk
└─sdb1             8:17   0  200G  0 part /data
```

what are the options to increase `sdb1` by +20g ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I increase the size of my active partition after resizing virtual disk?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/348586/how-do-i-increase-the-size-of-my-active-partition-after-resizing-virtual-disk)

Comment: not exactly , I appreciate if you give me example how to do the steps ( since we have very critical server )

Comment: I do not get the numbers to add up. From `xfs_growfs` it say `bsize=4096 blocks=34078464` which is `4096 × 34078464 ~ 130 G` And `df` say `1024 × 136247300 ~ 130 G`, but you want to increase it from 200 G to 220 G? Was the initial size 120 G perhaps? And you have attempted to increase it to 200 G w/o actually doing it? And now you want to increase it to 220 (from 130)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `xfs_growfs` resized only the XFS filesystem on `sdb1`, not the partition. You must first resize the partition using [parted](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Parted#Growing_partitions) or [fdisk](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1190213). Newer versions of `parted` have the `resizepart` command you can use, with older versions or `fdisk` you need to remove the partition and add a new one with same start and new end.

Based on your partition table type you'll also may need to fix you partition table (GPT has secondary header at the end of the device so it needs to be moved first), both `fdisk` and `parted` should prompt for this operation automatically if needed.